# error: Setup script exited with error: command 'i586-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, c, linux, gcc, honeypot

I try to use "python setup.py install"install conpot on linux. But it failed. error message is 
unable to execute 'i586-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'i586-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you need to install gcc, so that the package can be compiled

do either

```
apt-get install gcc
```

or

```
yum install gcc
```

depending on the type of your linux distribution